# Echo a two digit number in php

Tags: php, function, numbers, integer, echo

I really want to manipulate through to get some set of number ranges....

my code is working fine at the moment but the out put is what i have problem with.

i want to echo some thing like 00/00 , 00/01 , etc

but my code is giving me 0/0, 0/1, 0/2, etc

how do i go about this???

This is my code

```
<?php
 foreach (range(00, 99) as $no2) {
     foreach (range(00, 99) as $no3) {
        echo $no2 . "/" . "$no3</br>";
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Check out `sprintf()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo sprintf("%02s", $no2). "/" . sprintf("%02s", $no3)."</br>";
```

Comment: it not really working.....for me.....its giving me the values in tens like 02,  12, 22, 32, 42, ect.....

Comment: "%02s" is to echo the output in two digits. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.  Clean code would look like this: `printf("%02s/%02s<br>", $no2, $no3);`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah
i later did something like this that worked out perfectly well for me

```
   <?php
   $no2 = array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99');

  foreach ($no2 as $k ) {
foreach ($no2 as $a) {
 echo "$k" . "/". "$a";
  }

 ?>
```